# Perl illegal declaration of subroutine

Tags: perl

I have been trying to get the following program working for quite a while to no avail. I am new to perl and I haven't been able to figure it out.

The program is here

http://www.theiling.de/downloads/idx.cgi/schcompile-1.0003.tgz/*?lang=en

I have been trying to run this perl module in the Mac terminal, I've copied the module to @INC but I can't get it to work.

```
use HT::Conlang::S17

sub step_normalise_Latin($;$$) 

$result= step_normalise_latin ($quercus);

Illegal declaration of subroutine main::step_normalise_Latin at - line 3.
```

And here is some old discussion on the matter

http://archives.conlang.info/ga/gialqhia/thiantinkhuen.html

Answer (score 3):

You're missing semicolons after the `use` and the `sub` lines. Put them back in, and it'll work.

But actually, subroutine prototypes probably shouldn't be used - they're not what is commonly understood, and so they're only a good idea in particular niche situations.

Comment: No error pops up this time, thank you. However nothing happens, I should be getting on output of some kind. Also is it possible that the module isn't correctly installed as I just copy pasted it to my perl @INC directory

Comment: That seems pretty likely, yes. Usually you install modules with a package manager or CPAN, because then stuff like prerequisites happen. For standalone stuff, you usually unpack them to a separate directory and manually set 'use lib`.

Comment: how can I find the path to my separate directory? It is in a folder on my mac desktop. How will I know if the manual use lib has worked. Whenever I enter perldoc HT::Conlang::S17 I get no results.